# How to add values to a 2D Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have this dictionary where I want to map new values

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> myDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
myDictionary.Add(variableType.A.ToString(), new Dictionary<string, int>(variableType.A.ToString(), 0));
```

What would be a good idea to fix the second part of the code?

Comment: `myDictionary.Add(variableType.A.ToString(), new Dictionary<string, int>{ { variableType.A.ToString(), 0 } });`

Comment: I'd suggest calling `TryGetValue` **before** `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
var newValues = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> {
    {
        "test",
        new Dictionary<string, int> 
        {
            ["one"] = 1, // C#6, equivalent of doing {"one", 1}
            ["two"] = 2
        }
    }
};

//if you just want to assign.
myDictionary = newValues;
//if you want to add more entries to the dictionary
foreach (var (key, val) in newValues) 
{
    myDictionary.Add(key, val);
}
```

Or if you want to create a function:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> AddValuesToDictionary(string key, Dictionary<string, int> value)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach ( var (keys, vals) in value)
    {
        values.Add(keys, vals);
    } 
    return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> {
        {
            key,
            values
        }
    };
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
var p = new Program();
var newValues = p.AddValuesToDictionary(
    "test", 
    new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        ["one"] = 1,
        ["two"] = 2
    }
);
foreach (var (key, val) in newValues)
{
    myDictionary.Add(key, val);
}
```

And third approach using function above:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
var p = new Program();

var newValues = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>();


newValues.Add(p.AddValuesToDictionary(
    "test",
    new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        ["one"] = 1,
        ["two"] = 2
    }
));

newValues.Add(p.AddValuesToDictionary(
    "test2",
    new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        ["three"] = 3,
        ["four"] = 4
    }
));

foreach (var entry in newValues)
{
    foreach (var (key, val) in entry)
    {
        myDictionary.Add(key, val);
    }
}
```